# Formatting the output in a popup object

Tags: powershell, popup, newline

How do you make a multiple object variable appear properly in a popup box (one object per line)? Is it possible?

Let's say we have :

```
$test = (Get-Process -Name Win*).ProcessName
$test
(New-Object -COM Wscript.Shell).PopUp("$test", 0, "Title", "48")
```

It returns like this (each result on a new line in console but each result all on one line in the box which is my problem) :

[image]

Is there a way to add `n for a new line on every object? Thanks a lot

Comment: `Popup(($test -join "\`r\`n"), 0, "Title", "48")` might do it

Comment: Hmm first time i see that join operator, very nice, it works! Will be useful for others things as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$test = (Get-Process -Name Win*).ProcessName 
(New-Object -COM Wscript.Shell).Popup(($test -join "`r`n"), 0, "Title", "48")
```

the -join operator is the answer here, provided by TessellatingHeckler's comment.